# Json NullPointerException when calling readValue

Tags: java, json, serialization, libgdx

I decided to write my own read and write object methods by implementing the `Json.Serializable` interface because I was unhappy with how Json does it's automated object writing (it omits arrays). My write methods work properly, however for some reason I get a NullPointerException when I try to read the values back, as if I'm looking for a value by the incorrect name, which I'm certain I'm not doing; the write and read names are identical. These are my read and write methods and the Json output (the error occurs at the first `readValue()` call).

```
@Override
public void write(Json json)
{
    json.writeObjectStart(this.getName());

    json.writeValue("Level", level);
    json.writeValue("Health", health);
    json.writeValue("Allegiance", alle);
    json.writeValue("Stats", stats);
    json.writeValue("Has Moved", hasMoved);
    json.writeValue("Position", new Point((int)this.getX(), (int)this.getY()));

    json.writeObjectEnd();
}

@Override
public void read(Json json, JsonValue jsonData)
{
    level = json.readValue("Level", Integer.class, jsonData);
    health = json.readValue("Health", Integer.class, jsonData);
    alle = json.readValue("Allegiance", Allegiance.class, jsonData);
    stats = json.readValue("Stats", int[].class, jsonData);
    hasMoved = json.readValue("Has Moved", Boolean.class, jsonData);

    Point p = json.readValue("Position", Point.class, jsonData);
    this.setPosition(p.x, p.y);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
player: {
    party: {}
},
state: state1,
map: {
    foes: {
        units: [
            {
                class: com.strongjoshuagames.reverseblade.game.units.UnitWolf,
                Wolf: {
                    Level: 5,
                    Health: 2,
                    Allegiance: FOE,
                    Stats: [ 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5 ],
                    "Has Moved": false,
                    Position: {
                        x: 320,
                        y: 320
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Note that I've read objects from the same file this is being saved in before, so the file *shouldn't* be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure how the JSON library works, but I believe that since you do `json.writeObjectStart(this.getName());` in your write function, you have to 'reverse' this in your read function like everything else you wrote. In order to do this, you need to get the JsonValue's first child and get it's Level, Health, etc. I'm not sure about the API so I can't give exact code, but it'd be something like this:

```
level = json.readValue("Level", Integer.class, jsonData.child());
```

Think of it like this: I make a box and put a dictionary in it. I can't just lookup words in the box, I have to take the dictionary out first. Likewise, you need to get the object you wrote first before you can look up its fields.

Comment: Wow, it was that easy... Thanks for the analogy though :)

Comment: Does this mean I need to call `child()` an extra time every level I go into the object I'm writing? Like say the Object I'm writing has a field that is also a `Serializable` object, would I have to call `jsonData.child().child()` to read the values for that object?

Comment: @StrongJoshua Basically, yeah. I think there's probably a children() or getChild(name) method too, which gets all the children instead of just the first that you would use for further children. It's ok to call child() when you know only one child exists, but for fields like Serializable I'm sure there's a getChild(name) method or something, look through the API for the JSON library you're using to find it :)